# save generated gameobject to an array for shuffling

Tags: unity

hey everyone i have this script here that breaks down a sprite into pieces and makes each one a gameobject.im having touble saving them into an array so i can shuffle them as gameobjects.

```
 public void Start()
    {

        GameObject spritesRoot = GameObject.Find("SpritesRoot");
        Debug.Log("Array length: " + array2D.GetLength(0));

        for (int i = 0; i < array2D.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("x: " + array2D[i, 0]);
            Sprite newSprite = Sprite.Create(source, new Rect(array2D[i, 0], array2D[i, 1], array2D[i, 2], array2D[i, 3]), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
            GameObject n = new GameObject();
            SpriteRenderer sr = n.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            sr.sprite = newSprite;
            n.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(array2D[i, 0], array2D[i, 1],0),0);
            n.transform.parent = spritesRoot.transform;
        }

    }
```

my shuffle function is this

````
 public void Shuffle(GameObject[] gameObjects)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gameObjects.Length; i++)
        {

            // Find a random index
            int destIndex = Random.Range(0, gameObjects.Length);
            GameObject source = gameObjects[i];
            GameObject dest = gameObjects[destIndex];

            // If is not identical
            if (source != dest)
            {

                // Swap the position
                source.transform.position = dest.transform.position;

                // Swap the array item
                gameObjects[i] = gameObjects[destIndex];
            }
        }
    }
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you create an array for those objects. When you want to retain that array after the Start-method, then that should be on the level of the class, not a local variable:

```
private GameObject[] spawnedGameObjects;
```

Then you need to initialize that array to the number of entries you need:

```
spawnedGameObjects = new GameObject[array2D.GetLength(0)];
```

Then you put each newly created game object into entries of that array after you created it:

```
spawnedGameObjects[i] = n;
```

Then you shuffle it:

```
Shuffle(spawnedGameObjects);
```

Full code:

```
private GameObject[] spawnedGameObjects;

public void Start()
{

    GameObject spritesRoot = GameObject.Find("SpritesRoot");
    Debug.Log("Array length: " + array2D.GetLength(0));
    spawnedGameObjects = new GameObject[array2D.GetLength(0)];

    for (int i = 0; i < array2D.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("x: " + array2D[i, 0]);
        Sprite newSprite = Sprite.Create(source, new Rect(array2D[i, 0], array2D[i, 1], array2D[i, 2], array2D[i, 3]), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
        GameObject n = new GameObject();
        SpriteRenderer sr = n.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        sr.sprite = newSprite;
        n.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(array2D[i, 0], array2D[i, 1],0),0);
        n.transform.parent = spritesRoot.transform;
        spawnedGameObjects[i] = n;
    }

    Shuffle(spawnedGameObjects);

}
```

Comment: thank you for that, well i do want to be able to track each piece starting position so once shuffled i can drag and drop them back to their original position. its a puzzle game

Comment: @stratosla I see. Answer updated.